# Firestore order query based on order and bool

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to organize my queries of my firestore database by having a hueristic that I order everything in the database by and then a whereField section link in this link -> https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

where I perform a boolean comparison and omit results I don't want.

Examples are as such.

```
docRef.collection("Docs").whereField("type_", isEqualTo: "Video").order(by: "huer", descending: true).limit(to: 20).getDocuments()
```

The problem I'm having is that if I change the whereField values (omit based on different characteristics) I then need to make a new index.  This makes no sense to me, why wouldn't more than one index such as

```
type (arrow pointing up) huer (arrow pointing up)
type_ (arrow pointing up) huer (arrow pointing down)
```

counteract each other (they don't appear to).  Also why does the index require a direction on a value I'm only trying to boolean sort on?

I apologize to anyone if the arrow up down stuff doesn't make sense, its just how firestore displays indexes.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you switch the .whereField(isEqualTo) and .order(By) location?